# LSP clangd + company-mode writes ${n: Variable} strings

Tags: company-mode, lsp-mode, clang

I am not sure what exactly to google, on this issue. I have emacs 28.1 installed, with LSP-clangd and company-mode installed.

Suppose a function have signature `int func(int i, int j)`, then emacs autocomplete it as
`func(${1:int i}, ${2:int j})`. What are these `{$:int 1}` things? How can i make sure these are not written to buffer on autocomplete? Or are they part of some workflow I dont know about? (Like in sublime text you can jump to such fields using tab).

Comment: I'm guessing you need to install `yasnippet`. It should be mentioned in the docs of whatever LSP client you are using.